# setting function return value into public/static variable

Tags: php, mysql

student table contains:
id
firstname
lastname

function get_db_fields get student table fields.

```
class Student{

public function get_db_fields(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result){
         die("Failed :" . mysql_error());
        }
        $db_fields = array();
        while($field = mysql_fetch_field($result)){
           $db_fields[] = "'".$field->name."'";
        }
        return join(',',$db_fields);
    }

    public $db_fields = array($this->get_db_fields()); <--- This is not working

}
```

> return join(',',$db_fields) = 'id','firstname','lastname'

my question is how I am going set the return value into public $db_fields.
So public $db_fields will be "public $db_fields = array('id','firstname','lastname')"

What i've tried so far

1.)

```
public $db_fields = array($this->get_db_fields()); <--- This is not working
```

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\ieti\includes\student.php on line 33

```
2.) $database_fields = $this->get_db_fields();
```

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\ieti\includes\student.php on line 33

Comment: create a constructor and assign the returned value from `get_db_fields` to the member variable `db_fields`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a constructor and assign the returned value from `get_db_fields` to the member variable `db_fields`. Member variables can only be initialized with values that are evaluated at compilation.

```
class Student{

  public $db_fields;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db_fields = $this->get_db_fields();
  }

// Rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $db_fields = array($this->get_db_fields());
```

One using the 'array' here is not right, it should just be

```
public $db_fields =$this->get_db_fields();
```

And two, classes have constructors for this...

so

```
public function __construct(){
$this->db_fields = $this->get_db_fields();
}
```

Moreover use of mysql_query is now discouraged, if you are using object oriented already use **PDO**.